# Different output of Closure JavaScript (simple) counter

Tags: javascript, closures, output, counter, difference

Can someone explain me this different output of closure JS counter please.

**First snippet** *where output starts from 0:*

```
var counter = (function() {
    var count = 0;
    return function() {
        return count++;
    }
}());
console.log(counter()); // output: 0
console.log(counter()); // output: 1
console.log(counter()); // output: 2
```

**Second snippet** *where output starts from 1:*

```
var add = (function() {
    var counter = 0;
    return function() {
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }
})();

console.log(add()); // output: 1;
console.log(add()); // output: 2;
console.log(add()); // output: 3;
```

Why does it work like that way? Why first output starts from 0, and second one from 1? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`counter++;` has the ++ operator in postfix position, which tells it to return the value of counter first, and then increment after. So in your first example, that's what happens: 0 is returned, then it increments to 1; then 1 is returned, then it increments to 2, etc.

In your second example `counter++` still returns first and increments after, but nothing cares about the return value of the increment operation, since there's no left hand side to that line of code. Then a later line will return the now-incremented value.

It's also possible to use ++ in prefix position, in which case it will increment first and then return. You could use that to modify your first example to output 1, 2, 3.

```js
const counter = (function() {
    let count = 0;
    return function() {
        return ++count; //<--- changed to prefix
    }
}());
console.log(counter()); // output: 1
console.log(counter()); // output: 2
console.log(counter()); // output: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Snippet**

```
return count++;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
temp = count;
count = count + 1;
return temp;
```

so it starts from 0

**Second Snippet**

```
count++;
return count;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
temp = count;
count = count + 1;
return count;
```

so its initial value is 1;

**Pre Increment**

```
const counter = (function() {
  let count = 0;
  return function() {
    return ++count;
  }
}());
```

this results in increasing the value of count first then returning its value
which is identical to:

```
const counter = (function() {
  let count = 0;
  return function() {
    count = count + 1;
    return count;
  }
}());
```

**Post Increment**

```
const counter = (function() {
  let count = 0;
  return function() {
    return count++;
  }
}());
```

this results in increasing the value of count first then returning its value
which is identical to:

```
const counter = (function() {
  let count = 0;
  return function() {
    temp = count;
    count = count + 1;
    return temp;
}
}());
```